# Flutter: Stadium border with radius not overlapping text

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, rounded-corners

I'm trying to add a stadium shape fill behind some text. I want the flat sides of the background to match the width of the contained text, but can't figure out how to achieve this.

With this code:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    color: Colors.grey,
    shape: StadiumBorder(
    ),
  ),
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  child: Text('text'),
),
```

I get something looking like this:

[image: 1]

Whereas I am trying to achieve this:

[image: 2]

In the context of scaling text, so I can't just set the left and right margins enough that it looks right.

Answer (score 0):

Use symmetric padding

```
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical :5),
```